# as3 input text on ipad

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad

When on i-pad the user clicks on the input text the cursor goes below the sprite where the input text lives.

Once they are finished typing the input text goes where it is supposed.  Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue with AS3 and iPads and has been around for a while. I've certainly experienced the issue you're describing. Not much more I can add apart from you can try using StageText instead of AS3's default text system and as far as I can tell the issue isn't there. Hope this helps